# Greybird theme (editing): Modify Colors in nautilus file-manager

Tags: nautilus, themes, colors, gtk3, greybird

I am currently using Ubuntu-gnome 16.04 LTS with "Greybird" theme for both, GTK-2 & GTK-3 applications.
I really do like the theme, but I would like to modify it with regards to color-behaviour in nautilus (see below).

- (1) change the 'background' (???) color (currently #e3e3e3) behind non-selected folders and files in the folder-pane to the same one as the bg_color (#ffffff)
- (2) change the background (currently #dae0e6) in the side-panel, since it is hardly readable...

[image: (1) 'grey background' behind all folders and items; (2) bluish-grey background in sidepanel]

So I was looking into any *.css file of the theme, but albeit trial-and-erroring a lot, I was not able to identify the respective lines.

[My problem is NOT 'how to' modify a theme in general, but 'what' to modify in this particular case.]

Hints for which lines to look for would be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

1. Unfortunately I still have not found a way to change the view background of items (currently #e3e3e3) to the theme base_color (#ffffff), instead tough I was able to apply the color vice versa. To do this I had to add following line in the themes **gnome-applications.css** file:

> NautilusWindow .view {background-color: #e3e3e3;}

2. To adjust the side-panel to my likes I made the following changes in the themes **gtk-widgets.css** under the /************ sidebar ************/ header:

> ..sidebar GtkScrolledWindow {
>       background-color: mix(shade(@theme_base_color, 0.9), shade(@theme_selected_bg_color, 1.35), 0.1);
>       color: mix(@theme_text_color, @theme_base_color, 0.15);
>       -gtk-icon-style: symbolic;

....and...

> .sidebar-row:selected:focus {
>       border-width: 1px 0;
>       border-style: solid;
>       border-top-color: shade(@theme_bg_color, 0.85);
>       border-bottom-color: shade(@theme_bg_color, 1.12);
>       background-image: linear-gradient(to top,
>                                         shade(mix(@theme_base_color, @theme_selected_bg_color, 0.7), 1.05),
>                                         shade(mix(@theme_base_color, @theme_selected_bg_color, 0.7), 0.97)
>                                         );
>       color: #ffffff;
>   }

The result can be seen here: 
[Greybird theme modified for nautilus file manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlyFR.png)